# How to delete data from more than one table in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to **delete** the custom post in wordpress which will use wordpress default function. But I want to delete that post id from one more table which I have manually created to import the data from different tables of wordpress. I checked in inspect element of delete button which is showing:

```
<span class="delete">
    <a href="edit-tags.php?action=delete&amp;taxonomy=books&amp;tag_ID=2841&amp;_wpnonce=b5a0a7a688" 
       class="delete-tag aria-button-if-js" 
       aria-label="Delete “Mathew”" 
       role="button">Delete</a> | 
</span>
```

But I have tried to edit the **edit-tags.php** but it is not working. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an action on a hook can do what you want. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/before_delete_post
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post

You can search another one on the full list :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that.